# Controller to switch between 10 inputs

Tags: microcontroller

I need the controller to which I can connect 10(for example) inputs (lets say batteries), one input-select pin and one output. So, for example I send command to this chip - use input numer 3 and this chip connects input 3 to output.

I need controller name or something I can google.

Comment: Search for demultiplexer / demux. If the source signal is analog, search for analog demux.

Comment: I don't know if you will find what you need with a simple "google" search or not. It sounds like you are looking for some sort of "analog multiplexer" controlled by a microcontroller using a UART (serial interface).

Comment: It's unclear the voltage and current you want to switch, instead of saying "lets say batteries" why not just say what you really want to switch and for what reason?

Comment: 3.7 V 9000 mAh batteries

Comment: @JohnDow, but what do you want to do with the output? If you're measuring the voltage for instance the accepted answer will be fine. If you're using it to switch between batteries to drive a load (a motor for example) it will end badly.

Comment: Now I am using this for only measuring the voltage. But after all, using this measuring I want to use 3 of 10 batteries to get right 10 Volts.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't be better served by using a voltage-regulator to get your 10V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the output, but for starters you can use [74HC4051](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4051.pdf) - analog multiplexer/demultiplexer.

Comment: oh, except that it has only 8 channels, not 10. 74HC4067 is a 16 channel one.